# Combining jQuery scripts

Tags: jquery

How do I combine these 2 jQuery scripts?:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#header-nav').hide().before('<a href="#" id="toggle-header-nav"    class="skip-link skip-nav">MENU</a>');
    jQuery('a#toggle-header-nav').click(function() {
        jQuery('#header-nav').slideToggle(500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

AND:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.skip-link.skip-nav').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

The first one makes my header slide down slowly with the 'MENU' icon, and the second one gives a neat hamburger transition affect. But when I click on the hamburger it doesn't trigger the slide down affect. How do I combine the 2 to do this?

UPDATE: Maybe this will help explain better: if I remove the first jQuery the hamburger will trigger the slide down affect, but it doesn't "slide" (just appears) and there is no 'MENU' shown. If I have the first jQuery, the 'MENU' will only trigger the slide-down affect; clicking on the Hamburger won't.

Comment: So... It doesn't work separated into two `jQuery(document).ready` functions?

Comment: Correct, it only does each item separately.

Comment: Can you post some code so it's reproducible? Put it in a jsfiddle.net

Comment: I'm trying, but the code was built in Magento so there's a lot of linking items.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't work?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#header-nav').hide().before('<a href="#" id="toggle-header-nav" class="skip-link skip-nav">MENU</a>');
    $('a#toggle-header-nav').on("click", function() {
        $('#header-nav').slideToggle(500);
    });

    $('.skip-link.skip-nav').on("click", function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

Comment: If you read the last paragraph in the question, I don't think this is what they want help with.

Comment: This does the same as what is currently happening. I.e. it's not combining the functions of both.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#header-nav').hide().before('<a href="#" id="toggle-header-nav"    class="skip-link skip-nav">MENU</a>');

    jQuery('a#toggle-header-nav').click(function() {
        jQuery('#header-nav').slideToggle(500);
        return false;
    });
    jQuery('.skip-link.skip-nav').click(function(){
        jQuery(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

Why doesn't this work ?

Comment: This loses the function of the first jQuery for some reason.

Comment: Just tried your update too - it still does exactly the same as it does now. I.e. the hamburger isn't triggering the slide down effect.